# jQuery UI switchClass() not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I keep getting the error switchClass() is not a function in wordpress. Apparently since wordpress 3.5 the js effects core is included.

Do i need to specifically call it in? if so how would i do that?

i can see effect.min.js in the wordpress wp-includes/js/jQuery/ui/ folder

Comment: You have to show your code that is attempting to include the effect.min.js plugin

Answer (score 0):

to make work effect of [switchClass](https://jqueryui.com/switchClass/) jQuery function on WordPress,

add `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-effects-core' )` on your hook [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function.